# Trying to refresh 'expired' keystore

Tags: java, ant, keytool, jar-signing

I am trying to re-sign some jars using the ant task 'signjar' however it's telling me "The signer certificate has expired."

So I tried to re-generate the keystore hoping this would 'un-expire' it...

`keytool -genkey -keystore mykeystore -alias myalias`

but after entering the keystore password i get: "keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Key pair not generated, alias  already exists"

what am i doing wrong? do i need to delete the keystore to re-generate it or is there a simple way to refresh it so it's not expired?

thanks.

Comment: I had this problem when I was creating a new keystore, and Eclipse just took a long time to make the build.  I had to completely kill Eclipse and relaunch it.  The keystore was actually generated before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're mixing up the terms. A keystore contains keys, a key is something used for signing.

AFAIK, you're trying to put a new key into an old keystore using an existing alias (name). Why don't you simply used a new one? Either this or [delete](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3671/ablre/index.html) the old key from the keystore first. You don't need to drop the whole keystore.

Have a look at [portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/), this simple tool allows you to manipulate the keystore more easily.

Comment: mixing terms? very likely! i really don't like the documentation for this 'feature' of java ... will take a look at portecle thanks. i guess what i'm looking for is a simple way to extend the expiry of a signature.....

Comment: Strange.  I just deleted my .jks file and yet... I get this very same error.  For a key store with only 1 self-signed cert, why *shouldn't* I replace the whole thing?

Comment: @ebyrob: I'm not saying you shouldn't. Do whatever you think will work and if it doesn't, try portecle as it can help you to understand the problem. In case of a single key keystore, I'd suggest to use the same strong password for the keystore and the key (you surely avoid confusion and I really believe there's no security risk involved).

Comment: @maaartinus I use the same weak password for both.  Really, I wouldn't even sign this test version if Oracle didn't force me to sign it just to test the applet in a browser.

Answer (score 2):

For this simply regenerate you certificate again follow these steps.

```
   1)keytool -genkey -v -keystore mycertificate.keystore -alias mykey -keyalg 
   RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 1000
   2)  jarsigner -verbose -keystore mycertificate.keystore D:\app.apk mykey
   3) jarsigner -verify app.apk
     If it  will have done then shows a message "successfully verified"
   4) zipalign -v 4 D:\app.apk D:\signedapp.apk

  it will generate new certificate. enjoy :)
```