# Eclipse - Error While exporting?

Tags: android, eclipse

So I was just minding my own business exporting my Android application when an error showed up when I clicked finish on the destination and key/certificate checks.  Here is what the error said:

```
keytool error:javalang. Exception: Key pair not generated, alias <(my alias was right here)> already exists
```

Can somebody please help me?!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to refresh 'expired' keystore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823302/trying-to-refresh-expired-keystore)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have already created that alias in the keystore. When exporting try selecting use existing keystore.

*EDIT*:
You may be able to resolve the Davlik Error by referencing these two questions

[Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 - Exporting APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883178/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-exporting-apk)

["Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" on external JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar)

Comment: The thing was that i never created another keystore

Comment: ok now i used existing keystore and it has an error saying Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Comment: Is there a file of the same name at that location? Did you try making a new keystore? You can also try to update Eclipse ADT.